# How to use DOTENV to access Gilab variables or other secret variables that are present in cloud using process.env in Angular typescript?

Tags: angular, typescript, webpack, dotenv

I have one Big application in angular. Earlier it was in angular v5 that time i have used [NPM custom-webpack](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@angular-builders/custom-webpack) and created one script which will access process.env variables but then i have upgraded the version of Angular now its version 13.

After upgrading i am not able to use that script and custom-webpack NPM library is not working.

Does anyone have any idea how we can use process.env in Angular application?

Used this NPM packagehttps://www.npmjs.com/package/@angular-builders/custom-webpack

https://plainenglish.io/blog/setup-dotenv-to-access-environment-variables-in-angular-9-f06c6ffb86c0

Comment: What does "is not working" mean specifically? Given that you're on ng13, did you make sure to `npm install` the 13.x.x version of this library (and not the latest one - as it clearly states ng/cli16 minimum)

Comment: It's throwing a web pack error. during ng server and npm install @user776686